# how to use browser specific media queries like -ms-high-contrast, Edge in react material-ui

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, material-ui

### IE

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {

}

### Edge

@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto)  {

}

Comment: Please show some code showing the context on how you want to use this.

Answer (score 1):

To use the media queries in react material UI, you need to use [useMediaQuery](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/)

This is a CSS media query hook for React. It listens for matches to a CSS media query. It allows the rendering of components based on whether the query matches or not.

You should provide a media query to the first argument of the hook. The media query string can be any valid CSS media query, e.g. '(prefers-color-scheme: dark)'.

Example:

```
import mediaQuery from 'css-mediaquery';

function createMatchMedia(width) {
  return query => ({
    matches: mediaQuery.match(query, { width }),
    addListener: () => {},
    removeListener: () => {},
  });
}

describe('MyTests', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    window.matchMedia = createMatchMedia(window.innerWidth);
  });
});
```

So the media query will be the same. You just need to pass it as an argument for the media query string.

Comment: Hi @Deepak-MSFT I was wondering where someone could enter the number of pixels they were trying to use for their query? And is it mandatory to enter a css property in the query, since I would just like to find a component for a specific width.